# how can i return map inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, render

I am trying to render the data I received from my json data with the code I wrote.
my all code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Tabs from "@mui/material/Tabs";
import Tab from "@mui/material/Tab";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function VerticalTabs({ conditions }) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        flexGrow: 1,
        bgcolor: "background.paper",
        display: "flex",
        height: 224,
      }}
    >
      <Tabs
        orientation="vertical"
        variant="scrollable"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
        sx={{ borderRight: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}
      >
        <Tab label="Account" {...a11yProps(0)} />
        <Tab label="Sertifikalar" {...a11yProps(1)} />
      </Tabs>
      {conditions.map((condition, i) => {
        {
          condition.id === 1 && 
            return (
              <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                <h1>{condition.conditionName}</h1>
                {condition.sub_conditions.map((sub, ind) => {
                  <Title>
                    {sub.header}
                    {console.log(sub, "try")}
                  </Title>;
                })}
              </TabPanel>
            );
          }
        }
        {
            condition.id === 2 &&
              return (
                <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
                  <h1>{condition.conditionName}</h1>
                  {condition.sub_conditions.map((sub, ind) => {
                    <Title>
                     {sub.header}
                      {console.log(sub, "try")}
                    </Title>;
                  })}
                </TabPanel>
              );
            
          
      })}

    </Box>
  );
}
```

Here is the part of the code that I can't do:

```
{conditions.map((condition, i) => {
            {
              condition.id === 1 && 
                return (
                  <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                    <h1>{condition.conditionName}</h1>
                    {condition.sub_conditions.map((sub, ind) => {
                      <Title>
                        {sub.header}
                        {console.log(sub, "try")}
                      </Title>;
                    })}
                  </TabPanel>
                );
              }
            }
            {
                condition.id === 2 &&
                  return (
                    <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
                      <h1>{condition.conditionName}</h1>
                      {condition.sub_conditions.map((sub, ind) => {
                        <Title>
                         {sub.header}
                          {console.log(sub, "try")}
                        </Title>;
                      })}
                    </TabPanel>
                  );
                
              
          })}
```

My h1 tag is written to the screen, but my Title tag is not written to the screen. I couldn't figure out how to solve this. Obviously, I don't know where I made a mistake, because there are no errors reflected on the console, but I can't press the screen.

Comment: You aren't returning the `Title` component in your map method

Comment: How can I do that

Comment: Add a return statement?

Comment: Just remove the brackets, or with a `return` keyword before `<Title>`

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
xs.map(x => { f(x) });
```

…will return an array of `undefined`s!

When you have `x => { … }`, the contents of the block are treated as a function body. This means you *must* have a `return` expression in the block for it to return a value, e.g.

```
xs.map(x => { return f(x) });
```

You could also write:

```
xs.map(x => f(x));
```

…with no braces, however, this is only possible if the right-hand side of the arrow consists of a single statement.

Another thing to point out is that in the outermost `map`, you need to reenter the JSX context to sequence the two `TabPanel` elements together. You can do this using the [fragment syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Looking carefully through your code, it also looks like you might have a misplaced brace. I have reindented your code snippet and fixed this.

Using blocks and `return`s:

```
{
  conditions.map((condition, i) => {
    return <>{
      condition.id === 1 && (
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0} key={i}>
          <h1>{condition.conditionName}</h1>
          {condition.sub_conditions.map((sub, ind) => {
            return (<Title key={ind}>
              {sub.header}
              {console.log(sub, "try")}
            </Title>);
          })}
        </TabPanel>
      )
    }
    {
      condition.id === 2 && (
        <TabPanel value={value} index={1} key={i}>
          <h1>{condition.conditionName}</h1>
          {condition.sub_conditions.map((sub, ind) => {
            return (<Title key={ind}>
              {sub.header}
              {console.log(sub, "try")}
            </Title>);
          })}
        </TabPanel>
      )
    }</>
  })
}
```

Using implicit returns:

```
{
  conditions.map((condition, i) =>
    <>{
      condition.id === 1 && (
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0} key={i}>
          <h1>{condition.conditionName}</h1>
          {condition.sub_conditions.map((sub, ind) =>
            (<Title key={ind}>
              {sub.header}
              {console.log(sub, "try")}
            </Title>)
          )}
        </TabPanel>
      )
    }
    {
      condition.id === 2 && (
        <TabPanel value={value} index={1} key={i}>
          <h1>{condition.conditionName}</h1>
          {condition.sub_conditions.map((sub, ind) =>
            (<Title key={ind}>
              {sub.header}
              {console.log(sub, "try")}
            </Title>)
          )}
        </TabPanel>
      )
    }</>
  )
}
```

**EDIT**:

When producing elements from a `map`, we need to add a `key` to them so React can uniquely identify them when reloading. Typically, the index suffices for this purpose. I have edited my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should have return the component from the map function to render that
sorry for the bad code indentation but i think this should work for you

```
  {conditions.map((condition, i) => {
    
       if(condition.id==1){
        return (
          <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
            <h1>{condition.conditionName}</h1>
            {condition.sub_conditions.map((sub, ind) => {
              return(<Title>
                {sub.header}
                {console.log(sub, "try")}
              </Title>);
            })}
          </TabPanel>
        );
       }
       if(condition.id==2){
        return (
          <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
            <h1>{condition.conditionName}</h1>
            {condition.sub_conditions.map((sub, ind) => {
              return(<Title>
               {sub.header}
                {console.log(sub, "try")}
              </Title>);
            })}
          </TabPanel>
        );
       }
            })
      
            }
```